# Error in tracking lastNode at removing the Cycle of Nodes in LinkedLIst in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I created some Nodes with lastNode pointing head.
In removeCycle method Firstly detected the lastNode and then got error, when I try to make lastNode(i,e prev).next = null

```
public class loopsRemove {
    public static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;

        public Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    public static Node Head;
    public static Node Tail;
    public static int count =0;

   
    public static int removeCycle(){
        Node slow = Head;
        Node fast = Head;
          boolean Cycle = false;
    

        while(fast !=null && fast.next != null){
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
            count++;
            if(slow == fast){
                Cycle =true;
               break;
            }
        }
        if(Cycle == false){
            return 0;  //No Cycle and come out of function (int type is just to observe where function is returning
        }
        

        slow = Head;
        Node prev=null;  //to track previous of fast
        while(slow != fast){
            prev = fast;
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next;  //speed is same as slow now
        }
        prev.next =null;  //Making endNode.next to null
        return 1;   //int return is just to check weather my code is returning here or above
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Head = new Node(3); 
        Head.next = new Node(4);
        Head.next.next = new Node(5);
        Head.next.next.next = new Node(6);
        Head.next.next.next.next = Head;  //cycle formed
        System.out.println(removeCycle());

       
        System.out.println(Head.next.next.next.next.data); // null is expected at the last node if removeCycle works correctly
    }
}
```

Expected output:
1
null

current output :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot assign field "next" because "prev" is null
at loopsRemove.removeCycle(loopsRemove.java:44)
at loopsRemove.main(loopsRemove.java:55)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm works for breaking cycles anywhere, except when the cycle includes the head node.

To solve this you could temporarily prefix a dummy node before the head, use the algorithm on this longer list, and then omit that dummy node again.

The below code is your code except for the lines that reference `dummy`:

```
    public static int removeCycle() {
        Node dummy = new Node(0); 
        dummy.next = Head; // Prefix a dummy node before the head node
        Node slow = dummy; // Apply the algorithm on this longer list
        Node fast = dummy;
        boolean Cycle = false;

        while(fast !=null && fast.next != null){
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
            count++;
            if(slow == fast){
                Cycle =true;
               break;
            }
        }
        if(Cycle == false){
            return 0;
        }
        

        slow = dummy;  // Start at the temporary head
        Node prev=null;
        while(slow != fast){
            prev = fast;
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next;
        }
        prev.next =null;
        return 1;
    }
```

Note that in your main program you should not try to print the data of a `null` reference. Just print the `next` property that is expected to be `null`:

```
        System.out.println(Head.next.next.next.next);
```

Because the dummy node is not referenced by anything else than a local variable, it can be garbage collected after `removeCycle` returns.

Comment: I understood your ''Fist line'' in explaination ,,But can you tell  the logic behind intializing the fast and slow to a node before head..     and does the same code works when my Cycle exclude Head..?

Comment: Is it like my code won't work when head is included, Hence prefix Node so that  head becomes non-Head part and my cycle rejoins at non head part..?

Comment: Just think of it as if you really had a list with the dummy head as its new head. Then it is like you did in your code: you start at that head. The difference is that now we know that the (new) head will not be part of the cycle. This is needed because if the original head is part of the cycle this algorithm doesn't do the job. By adding a new head in front, that situation is avoided. Now it will work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The first while ends when

```
        if(slow == fast){
            Cycle =true;
           break;
        }
```

Then

```
    slow = Head;
```

doesnt change anything, in this case (3->4->5->6) slow is already head, slow==fast is still true and the following while is never entered

```
    Node prev=null;  //to track previous of fast
        while(slow != fast){
             prev = fast;
             slow = slow.next;
             fast = fast.next;  //speed is same as slow now
         }
         prev.next =null;
```

meaning that prev is null when you try to assign prev.next.

Edit:

The reason that your code won't work without the dummy in trincots answer is that when there are no elements that are not part of the circle, then the first while stops when slow==fast==Head, meaning that the next-reference to head is lost. Using the dummy, slow==fast at the element before head (in case there are no non-circular elements, otherwise earlier), so that prev.next can be reassigned to null. And, there's no risk that the second while is skipped. (This can also be avoided by using a do-while.)

Comment: `while(node.next!=null && node.next !=Head) {
        node=node.next;
    }`  This works when my Cycle rejoining at Head(i,e. First Node)  what if the cycle joining anywhere in the middle, then this won't work right..!?

Comment: That's right, it won't work if the linked list looks like the number 6, a circle with a tail...